# xliff file: Change source-language to "Base"?

Tags: xcode, localization, xliff

I originally develop an app in English, then translating it to German.

During the course, instead of changing the files in the Base Localization, I added an English localisation to accommodate changes. I thought that was smart …

Now I got back xliff files from some (non professional) translators. The source-language attribute is "en".

However, upon import, Xcode now complains that there is a mismatch, with this example:

In my Localizable.strings file for English, there is

"%d. What you should do:" = "%d. What you should do next:";

In the Xliff there is:

```
  <file original="Foo/en.lproj/Localizable.strings" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="fr">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="%d. What you should do:">
        <source>%d. What you should do:</source>
        <target>%d. Ce que vous devriez faire :</target>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
```

Xcode complains when importing, because "%d. What you should do:" is not "%d. What you should do next:"

Is there any way to tell Xcode to just use it? To use the "Base" Localization as reference instead of the en?

Or is there another way besides me changing all the strings?